# GDB: How can I find the in-memory total size of loaded symbols (msymbols, psymbols, symbols)?

Tags: c++, c, gdb, freebsd

Our dev environment is configured in such a way that when we run the debug version of our code, it breaks into gdb on a crash or ^C. With some recent changes this is not happening anymore (exiting the program instead of breaking into gdb), and I'm suspecting the increase in symbols size is causing this issue.

Is there a way to find the sizes of msymbols, psymbols & symbols (memory consumption of symbols when they are loaded into the gdb session)?

Also, is there a way to limit the memory used for symbols in gdb? Google mentions HP's version supports such feature  - and with other versions the only way out is to disable shared lib symbols auto-load and load them on demand. What would it take to have HP like support on, say FreeBSD?

Thankyou.

Comment: Try just running GDB on the program directly and see how big the process is.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get that information directly.  You could add it pretty easily, but I personally wouldn't bother.

Your report isn't really detailed enough to understand what is going on.  However I tend to doubt the behavior you are seeing is caused by gdb's size.

You can disable automatic loading of shared library info using `set auto-solib-add`.